# SQL update based on value from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

As shown in the figure, I have four tables. Only `TableB` and `TableBChild` have a foreign key relationship.

What I want to achieve here is to determine whether
`TableBChild.MemberID` matches `TableA.memberNo` where `TableB.isgood` is true

If not batch update `isvalid` to false where condition is not satisfy.

But I am unable to compare `TableBChild.MemberID` to `Member.MemberNo`.

```js
Update TableB
Set IsValid = 0
From TableA as A
INNER JOIN TableB as B ON A.TableBNo = B.TableBNo And IsGood = 1
INNER JOIN TableBChild as BC ON B.TableBID = BC.TableBID
                             AND BC.MEMBERID != SELECT MemberID 
                                                FROM Member 
                                                WHERE MemberNo = A.MemberNo // This line is not working
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `NOT IN` instead of `!=` like this:

```
Update TableB
Set IsValid = 0
From TableA as A INNER JOIN TableB as B
                      ON A.TableBNo = B.TableBNo And IsGood = 1
                 INNER JOIN TableBChild as BC
                       ON B.TableBID = BC.TableBID
AND BC.MEMBERID NOT IN ( SELECT MemberID from Member Where MemberNo = A.MemberNo )
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your last line :

```
AND BC.MEMBERID != (SELECT MemberID from Member Where MemberNo = A.MemberNo)
```

Comment: This `()` will not change anything!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
UPDATE TableB
SET IsValid = 0
WHERE TableBID NOT IN 
(
-- this will select TableBID's satisfying:
-- TableB.IsGood is true, 
-- and corresponding TableBChild has memberID that exists in TableA.MemberNo
SELECT tbc.TableBID
FROM TableBChild tbc
INNER JOIN TableB tb ON tb.TableBID = tbc.TableBID
INNER JOIN TableA ta ON tbc.MemberID = ta.MemberNo
WHERE tb.IsGood = 1
)
```